# Creating a single thread for multiple objects

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a thread which I am creating whenever an object is created of the class , the thread I am creating in the constructor itself. So, depending on how many objects are created , the number of threads will be equal to number of objects created. But I want to create only a single thread , no matter how many objects are created..

Any help would be appreciated.

I can't put the code here as it is too big.
A simple suggestion will be helpful for me.

Comment: Just add a bool and check if the thread has been created... ? Where is the problem ?

Comment: Do I need to pass that bool every time to the constructor ?

Comment: Have you heard of `static` ? Put one in that class and use it in the `ctor`.

Comment: I was thinking somewhat similar of it. Okay let me check whether it will work or not.

Comment: A static variable to check whether the thread is already created or not, right ?

Comment: How are you creating your thread? You can make static variable that refers/holds your thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [singleton design pattern](http://www.devartplus.com/3-simple-ways-to-create-singleton-in-c/) to restrict an object to have one (or specific number of) instance(s). Moreover, look at [this](http://preshing.com/20130930/double-checked-locking-is-fixed-in-cpp11/) for a thread safe implementation if you create object from multiple threads.

Comment: I want to create multiple objects so singleton design pattern may not work.

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla but you can use its idea to implement (local static variable or put thread to a singleton class) to create just one thread...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to move thread into separate class and make its static object in your main class t.e. something like this

```
MyThreadClass {
    // implement your code to handle thread
};

MyObjectClass {
    static MyThreadClass* myThread; // static object to keep single thread  
};

main() {
    // create multiple MyObjectClass 
}
```

I made very simple [code](https://gist.github.com/mkamilov/b5ee19a0ab24f1690b6ffcbbafe51be4) to check this concept with std::thread